# Diagonal match in Connect 4

Tags: c#, forms

Hey guys I'm developing a Connect 4 game in Windows form application in C# everything works perfectly I'm just stuck in the diagonal part. This is what I've developed for the left down diagonal check but I'm not sure if it works perfectly. It's working from the first tile which is (1,1) but I can't tell about the other tiles. I also wanted to know how to create another method for the other side diagonal match. (gameButtons is my 2D array and my form is 6 rows and 7 columns) This is my method:

```
private void checkForDiaMatch()
    {
        int countBlue = 0;
        int countRed = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (gameButtons[i, i].BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                countBlue++;
            }
            else
            {
                countBlue = 0;
            }
            if (gameButtons[i, i].BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                countRed++;
            }
            else
            {
                countRed = 0;
            }

            if (countBlue >= 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a blue diagonal match");
                MessageBox.Show("Blue wins!");
            }
            else if (countRed >= 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a red diagonal match");
                MessageBox.Show("Red wins!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Edit: So since I took some help from the comment section I created this but it's still not working. I tried going for the diagonal right match but no luck yet.

```
private void checkForDiaMatch(int col,int targetRow)
    {
        int countBlue = 0;
        int countRed = 0;
        int xLocation = gameButtons[col, targetRow].Location.X/50;
        int yLocation = gameButtons[col, targetRow].Location.Y/50;
        //string epop = Convert.ToString(xLocation);
        //MessageBox.Show(epop);

        if (7 > xLocation + 1 && 6 > yLocation + 1)
        {
            if (gameButtons[xLocation + 1, yLocation + 1].BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                countBlue++;
                string kappaBlue = Convert.ToString(countBlue);
                MessageBox.Show(kappaBlue);
            }
            else
            {
                countBlue = 0;
            }
            if (gameButtons[xLocation + 1, yLocation + 1].BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                countRed++;
                string kappaRed = Convert.ToString(countRed);
                MessageBox.Show(kappaRed);
            }
            else
            {
                countRed = 0;
            }
```

Comment: I would think about two things: 1. How do you detect a diagonal manually? 2. When would you call this method, and at that point, what information do you have? You shouldn't have to analyze the entire board each time. My guess is that you would call this each time someone places a piece, and you know the location of that piece. From that location, how would you detect a diagonal?

Comment: _"but I can't tell about the other tiles"_ -- why not? Did you test this method with the other tiles? You should have, and having such tests (see "unit testing") available will help you write and debug your code. For questions on Stack Overflow, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having, with a detailed explanation of what that code does and what you want instead, and a detailed explanation of what you've tried so far to fix the problem, and a detailed explanation of what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Comment: @RufusL So, the method is called when a user places a tile somewhere. The only information I have is that the user clicked somewhere that's why I created the method to check the whole board. I have 2 more methods checking for vertical and horizontal, i'm planning to put them together in one method later when I create all the methods I need. The piece is stored in a variable already but only the piece that the user clicked not where the piece ended.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tested the other tiles but it doesn't seem to work. It only works from the top left tile and diagonally down until there are no more tiles.

Comment: @jk485921 So you know where they clicked, and presumably you know where the piece landed that they just put on the board, right? If you just check for diagonals from the piece that was placed, you should be good.

Comment: @RufusL I've tried it before, but when the tile was placed on one of the 4 edges of the board I would get an error about the index being out of the array. The method I posted is the closest I could reach on getting a diagonal match.

Comment: @jk485921 Yeah, you will have to check that you're not going out of bounds. What I would do is have an argument for the function that gives the coordinates of the piece that was just placed. Then from there you search down and left for a diagonal (until you get to the edge of the board) and if that succeeds return true. If it fails, search down and right for a diagonal. If that succeeds return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: @RufusL I'm getting confused by using coordinates so I prefer not using them yet, I guess this will be possible with the row and column right?

Comment: @RufusL What I was thinking is declare 2 ints at the start one with the X location/50 and the other will be the Y location /50 and then add them (or substract depending the diagonal match i need to check) at the i so something like:  if gameButtons[xLocation + i, yLocation - i].BackColor==Color.Blue {...}. So I guess right now the only thing that is missing is to check if the index is out of the arrays but I don't have any idea how to do that

Comment: You can find the array bounds using `gameButtons.GetLength(indexToFindLengthOf)`

Comment: So I just place an if inside the for loop before everything happens to check for the index?

Comment: @RufusL I'm getting the same error when I try to find the array bounds of an index, that index is out of the bounds.

Comment: Well that means that you're trying to access an index that is greater than the array bounds. It shouldn't be too hard to step through the code and see where you're having trouble. It's not exactly clear to me why you're dividing the Location by 50, and you are missing some parenthesis in your `if` statements to force the addition to happen before the "greater than" comparison - it should be: `if (7 > (xLocation + 1) && 6 > (yLocation + 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most helpful thing would be to draw your board and indexes on paper, and write the indexes of any random diagonal connect 4:

```
-------------------------------            -------------------------------
5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |5,6|            5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4 |   |   |   |   |   |4,5|   |            4 |   |4,1|   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   |   |   |3,4|   |   |            3 |   |   |3,2|   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |2,3|   |   |   |            2 |   |   |   |2,3|   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |            1 |   |   |   |   |1,4|   |   | 
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |            0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+            --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |              | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

We can see that from any point we need to check in two directions: up/right + down/left (like a `/`), and up/left + down/right (like a `\`). We want to count in both these directions the number of same-colored pieces as the one that we started from. As soon as the total number is 4, we can return true. If neither directions has a total of 4 matching pieces, we return false.

I played with this a little, and came up with the following method that works for me. Your classes are probably slightly different (I just did a console app), but hopefully the logic will help:

```
private bool CompletesDiagonal(int pieceRow, int pieceCol)
{
    var colorToMatch = Board[pieceRow, pieceCol]; // Board is a ConsoleColor[7,6] array

    var matchingPieces = 1; // We will count the original piece as a match

    // Check forward slash direction '/'

    // First check down/left (decrement both row and column up to 3 times)
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        var row = pieceRow - counter;
        var col = pieceCol - counter;

        // Make sure we stay within our board
        if (row < Board.GetLowerBound(0) || col < Board.GetLowerBound(1)) { break; }

        if (Board[row, col] == colorToMatch)
        {
            matchingPieces++;
            if (matchingPieces == 4) return true;
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    // Next check up/right (increment both row and column up to 3 times)
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        var row = pieceRow + counter;
        var col = pieceCol + counter;

        // Make sure we stay within our board
        if (row > Board.GetUpperBound(0) || col > Board.GetUpperBound(1)) { break; }

        // Check for a match
        if (Board[row, col] == colorToMatch)
        {
            matchingPieces++;
            if (matchingPieces == 4) return true;
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    // If we got this far, no match was found in forward slash direction,
    // so reset our counter and check the back slash direction '\'
    matchingPieces = 1;

    // First check down/right (decrement row and increment column)
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        var row = pieceRow - counter;
        var col = pieceCol + counter;

        // Make sure we stay within our board
        if (row < Board.GetLowerBound(0) || col > Board.GetUpperBound(1)) { break; }

        // Check for a match
        if (Board[row, col] == colorToMatch)
        {
            matchingPieces++;
            if (matchingPieces == 4) return true;
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    // Next check up/left (increment row and decrement column)
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++)
    {
        var row = pieceRow + counter;
        var col = pieceCol - counter;

        // Make sure we stay within our board
        if (row > Board.GetUpperBound(0) || col < Board.GetLowerBound(1)) { break; }

        // Check for a match
        if (Board[row, col] == colorToMatch)
        {
            matchingPieces++;
            if (matchingPieces == 4) return true;
        }
        else { break; }
    }

    // If we've gotten this far, then we haven't found a match
    return false;
}
```

Here's the result of a diagonal win:

[image]

Comment: Props to you for making the actual game just to be able to write an answer! :D

Comment: @RufusL   Hey, thanks for the well-elaborate answer (and the help of course). I've tried your method after changing a couple of this such as the counters ( I made them from 0 till 3) and the classes. I'm still getting the error that I'm outside of the array bounds at some cases though.

Comment: @RufusL To be honest, I really don't know why am I getting that the index is out of the bounds because every value the compiler returns to me is correct (for my information) for example i'm getting that the index is out the bounds of the array because the column variable is 4.

Comment: @jk485921 Sorry you're still having trouble. I would recommend adding some logging (if you're using winform, you can just log to a multi-line textbox or something) or stepping through the code in the debugger. If when you're testing you notice only certain patterns trigger the exception, set a breakpoint just before you know you're about to trigger it so you don't have to step through too many loops. Good luck!

Comment: @poke Ha! Thanks. Sometimes someone else's problem becomes a fun challenge. And I actually had pretty good time playing the game when I was done!! :)

Comment: @RufusL No need to say sorry haha, you really helped me. I managed to fix this but now I have another problem that when I click the last I get the same error "Index was found outside the array bound" and the compiler returns  that colorToMatch variable is null which I don't really know what is it. If I click the first column, I get that the col is -1.

Comment: @RufusL Something else I wanted to ask :D. Wouldn't be easier to use the method I told you on the other comment with the coordinates? I also forgot to tell you that I divide the locations because my form is 500x500 and each button is 50x50 so the first (x,y) for example is (50,50) and not (1,1)

Comment: @jk485921 Easier how? You have the controls in an array with indexes that are easy to map and bounds that are easy to determine (see my first "drawing" above). You are doing extra math to find a location you already have - you might as well just set `xLocation = col` and `yLocation = targetRow`. Also, it's common practice to use `[row,col]` for array layout, and you seem to be doing `[col,row]`. Lastly, be careful when using control positions for math. You should use the `.Width` and `.Height` properties in case they change, and take into account any padding between controls.

Comment: @RufusL I don't know tbh the indexes part is confusing me a lot, working with coordinates seems easier to me since everything I try i'm getting the same error again and again that says the index is outside the bounds of the array. But anyway I gave up on it for a bit, since I'm trying to do that for 2 days, to work on other things for the game. Thanks a lot for your help and information.

Comment: No problem. You'll get it soon enough. It can be confusing also because the arrays are `0`-based, so the "first" item is at index `0`. The indexes are basically the same as coordinates. Think of a multi-dimentional array as an array of rows, each of which has an array of columns. So if you reference `SomeArray[2,3]`, you are saying, "Give me the third row (2 + 1), and in that row give me the value of the item in the fourth column (3 + 1)." Good luck and don't give up! Once you get it, it's not too bad, and you definitely need to get it! :)

Comment: @RufusL So after a bit editing I managed to make it work but I still have a minor issue. I edited the code a bit so the first variable ( var colorToMatch ) I made it equal to the back color so: var colorToMatch = gameButtons[col,targetRow].BackColor . So the problem is, when I click on the last column I get the error "Index is outside the bounds of the array" and the fault is on the colorToMatch. The debugger returns that colorToMatch is "{Name=0, ARGB=(0,0,0,0)}" but I have no idea what does that mean.

Comment: The problem is that the value of one of your indexes is larger than the bounds for that array. It could be that you transposed the indexes between the caller and the callee. In my code, I always use `[row,col]`. In your code, you were doing `[col,row]`. So if you're on the last column (index `6`) and the first row (index `0`), and you call the method like `CompletesDiagonal(6, 0)`, you will get an out-of-bounds exception because it expects the row first, and there is no row with index `6`. If you get really stuck, you might consider opening a new question with your latest code.

Comment: Oh, and the reason the color has all zero values is because it hasn't been initialized, because the object referring to it doesn't exist. The color is not part of the reason for the exception.

Comment: Can I somehow make it to be initialized before?

Comment: Okay I changed everything back like yours. Now when I click the last column I get that colorToMatch is null.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the line: `var colorToMatch = gameButtons[col, targetRow].BackColor;`. The issue is that either `col` or `targetRow` is too large. That's what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RufusL I don't think so. Every time I get the error the col or targetRow are always inside their bounds. But I removed the .BackColor now and basically just copied yours but I still get an error when clicking the last column.

Comment: Are you still initializing your arrays with 10 instead of 9? That could be why. I can't hemp without seeing the code. Please post a new question